# Beautifulsoup web scraper issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, web-scraping

I'm using BeautifulSoup and mechanise to find some content from a web page. The thing is that SOMETIMES the string I'm looking for is not found. I don't know what could be a problem

It worked fine for many months for many web pages but suddenly it stopped working. Then I have to restart my program and hope for the right result.

The problem is in `data.find(text=re.compile('string to find'))`. The web page is always downloading but the string sometimes is not found. I think the problem could be in wrong `HTML` formatting of the loaded page? Any idea?

Here is very small part of the code I'm working with and it's only for your review

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as soup
from mechanize import Browser
import sys, re

def get_page(url):
    mech = Browser()
    page = mech.open(url)
    return page.read()

def test():
    data = soup(get_page('some url'))

    div_pages = data.find(text=re.compile('string to find'))

    try: pager = div_pages.strip().split(' ')
    except:
        print div_pages
        sys.exit()

    print 'ok'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Try logging the page when your required data is not found. It might be a problem with the page you're loading, not the script.

Comment: @Shawn Chin: okej so i figured it out. this particular website is currently in process of testing new design. i dont know the exact equation but it seems to me like one in the twenty page view load is in different design so my scrapers wont work :) so rule number one: be sure what are you scraping!

Answer (score 0):

I helped someone out with a similar problem and it turned out to be the encoding of the string. This link (from their docs) might help you on the way - [Beautiful Soup Gives You Unicode, Dammit](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit)

Comment: thanks for help, this wasnt a case. see my comment above to Shawn Chin about a problem solving

Comment: No problems - just thought I'd include it in case it helped - happy scraping